# Which SQL Server files/folders should be excluded from disk write protection (FBWF) on a windows embedded standard system?

Tags: sql-server, windows

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express with native reporting services on a Windows embedded standard (x64) system that needs to have disk write protection (FBWF) enabled.

Since I'm new to SQL Server, I'm unsure of which files that needs to be excluded from write protection for the database to continue to work as intended by its devs after, let's say, a restart of the hardware.

I found [this MSDN page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows-embedded/2008/12/03/disk-protection-in-windows-embedded-standard-more-than-just-a-useful-feature/) that says that the following files should be excluded (for the database only, not reporting services):

- \MyDatabase\DB.mdf
- \MyDatabase\DB.ldf
- \logs

but I'm leaning more towards that i should exclude the following full folders just to cover my back when it comes to not losing anything from the database. This is a way of reasoning that I generally despise when it comes to programming, but I guess that's why I'm asking here about this...

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services

Comment: Changed to sql-server tag. (SQL is a language. It has no files or installation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned only about the data written to the database, then nothing else is required.
.MDF is the primary database file and .LDF is the transaction log file.

However, if there are configuration or log information that should be kept, then yes, you will need to exclude the log folders such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\LogFiles.